# Replace words without replacing them if they appear in another open compound word

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, replace

I have a paragraph of text that may contain a single word ("dog") that is also contained in another open compound word ("dog walker").  I have a glossary of words that need to match the word found in the paragraph exactly.

I map over the glossary terms, and create a key value object to be used in `.replace()`

```
 const wordTermArray = this.props.glossaryTerms.map(i => [
        `${i.glossaryItem}`,
        `<a href="#" class="glossary-item">${i.glossaryItem}</a>`,
      ]);

      const wordTermObject = Object.fromEntries(wordTermArray);
```

And here is the object being used in `.replace()`

```
 const replaceText = text.replace(
        /(\w+)/g,
        (match, key) => wordTermObject[key] || match,
      );
```

But the problem is using .replace() could possibly match "dog" with the "dog" in "dog walker".       So, how would I match the word or open compound word exactly as it appears in the glossary without having them cross replace each other?

I'm not limited to Regex, and also not against using a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a regex out of your glossary items after sorting them by length in descending order, and then wrapping the matches with a tag:

```
const glossaryTerms = ['dog', 'dog walker'];
glossaryTerms.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.length - a.length;
});
const wordTermRegex = new RegExp( glossaryTerms.map(i => i.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join("|"));
// => /dog walker|dog/
const replaceText = "dog walker and a dog".replace(wordTermRegex, '<a href="#" class="glossary-item">$&</a>');
// => <a href="#" class="glossary-item">dog walker</a> and a dog
```

See the [JS demo](https://tio.run/##XY9BboMwEEX3nGLkRsFugzkAga56gSq7QKUJTAipsZHtNKmSnJ0Slaalq/kajf57s8cPdKVtOh9pU1Hfl0Y7D7UyzqH9XJFtHaSwDitThwu4DTiieicbFkkwOZPOWM@3B136xmiOC9iIcwBgyR@sho1UpGu/gwhwjElwFUnwTTwaW91qXqmm00DUdIQhv5w6PrWRLXa8gTSDRlrqFJbE43WUx3n@Nnt8epZcXNZ5cb4WcT0I5/lsHgoh96bRnF2YGIlGkVSm5hPu3WYsXtHJDy7s92tAXQHCsGB3@qRiQC4Rdpa2KXtgUCp0LmU/H0SNp5Zls/kyxiz8p/IHKpK@/wI).

The `$&` pattern in the replacement refers to the whole match.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/36eZ7J/1)